# Comparing Time (only) in two columns and returning value from the third column

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, time, comparison

I need to call the corresponding value of time from column F in column B.

[image]

Tried using Vlookup and match/index functions. But they are not working for time. If you know a quick method please share.

Comment: Vlookup works as long as your time columns are simply time (ie, one is not a date that is abbreviated down to a time while other is just time). Or they would also work if both were converted to text.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get it to work. The first 3 cells in column B will come up with #N/A because that value is not in your table (as seen in cell B3), but the formula I put in B2 has a IFNA ahead of the VLOOKUP to address that.  Formula B3 - =VLOOKUP(A3,E$2:F$4,2,0)

[image]

Hopefully, that helps